# "Waiting for Sound System to respond." error dialog

Tags: 10.10, sound, pulseaudio, indicator-sound

I'm having a nasty problem with the Sound Menu on my Ubuntu 10.10 Installation.
What happens is that the sound control icon is blocked, and I can't control the master volume.
If I try to get to the *Sound Preferences* I get a little Pop-Up Window saying:

> Waiting for Sound System to respond...

Don't know what to do... apart of that, sound works great.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself.

The problem was that, for some reason I don't know or remember, I was not the "owner" of my home folder, and because of that I couldn't kill the pulseaudio process... I realized that when Ubuntu tried to update the `.ICEauthority` file located in my home folder and had trouble with the permissions.

Running the following command should solve the `.ICEauthority` and volume control not working for people with the same problem as me:

```
sudo chown "user":"user" /home/"user"
```

And thats it! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `pulseaudio` daemon isn't running. Try to do `pulseaudio --start` from a terminal and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When i run that (I've already tried before), i receive an odd message: "E: core-util.c: Home directory /home/paulo not ours.
W: lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
E: main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock"